# Критерий сравнения и классы

Tags: c++, классы

Хочу написать шаблон класса AVL_tree но столкнулся с проблемой: а как передать критерий сравения? Всмысле как написать конструктор для класса, который бы принял функтор, вроде:

```
struct foo {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {return a > b};
}

...

AVL_tree<int> a(foo);
...
```

или

```
AVL_tree<int, foo> a;
```

Comment: Например, воспользоваться `std::function`. Но - раз у вас шаблон - добавить еще один параметр типа для функционального объекта и не мучиться...

Comment: Просто сделайте шаблонный конструктор.

Comment: @Harry не совсем понял про "добавить еще один параметр типа для функционального объекта"?

Comment: Ну, у вас есть что-то вроде `template<typename ElemType> AVL_Tree` - где `ElemType` - тип данных, хранящихся в узлах дерева. Делаем `template<typename ElemType, typename Compare> AVL_Tree` - где `Compare` представляет собой тип вашего функционального объекта.

Comment: @Harry a, это, понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример передачи компаратора через шаблонный параметр:

```
#include <functional>

template <class T, 
          class Compare = std::less<T> >
class AVL_tree {
    ...
    // необходимый код для АВЛ дерева
    //-----

    // пример использования компаратора
    bool compare(T const & a, T const & b) const {
        return Compare{}(a, b);
    }
};

struct foo {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {
        return a >= b;
    }
};

int main() {
    AVL_tree<int, foo> tree;
}
```

Comment: `Compare(a, b)` -> `Compare{}(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Использование указателя на функцию не подойдёт?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo{
private:
    bool (*cmp)(int a, int b); //компаратор
public:
    Foo(bool (*cmp)(int a, int b) = nullptr):cmp(cmp){//передача в конструкторе
    }
    void call(){ // вызов компаратора
        if(cmp != nullptr){
            cmp(1, 2);
        }
    } 

};

bool first (int a, int b){//первый компаратор
    cout << "\nFirst!";
    return true;
}

bool second (int a, int b){//второй компаратор
    cout << "\nSecond!";
    return false;
}

int main() {
    Foo f_foo(first), s_foo(second);
    f_foo.call();
    s_foo.call();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так тоже можно, но с шаблонным параметром лучше в том плане, что адрес функции определяется на момент компиляции, тем самым компилятору проще оптимизировать код (например, заинлайнить функцию). Плюс не нужно мучиться с указателями, проверять на nullptr. Все проверки сделает за тебя компилятор (на совместимость типов и т.п.).